# Need to change width origin

Tags: html, css

I have a 0 width element, and on hover of a button near it the width of the element changes to 400, and it appears from left to right with 0.3s transition, but what if I need it to appear from right to left?.

Comment: First show your code

Answer (score 0):

Use float: right

html:

```
<div id="a">
</div>
<div id="b">
</div>
```

css:

```
#a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
    background: blue;
}

#b {
   width: 0px;
}

#a:hover + #b {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
}
```